# Create new table from existing when existing is full

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

We use MS SQL Express to datalog from a program. When the program thinks it has stored enough (500.000 lines) it just start overwrite the table.

I know how to create a table but I need to create a new table when the existing table gets close to its limits set by the program. The new table should be named something like "TableName_TodaysDate".

We cannot alter the program code to extend the limits of 500.000 lines to more or unlimited.

I believe this is possible and could be run as a task in either MS SQL Express or Windows itself.

Any ideas or solutions on this?

Comment: Are you trying to retain the existing records?  Presumably, the program won't be able to use a new table because you cannot alter the code.  Would one big history table be better than a number of smaller tables?

Comment: I'm with destination-data here. Create a single archive table, and move records from the main table to the archive table whenever the main table gets dangerously large. It will make your life much easier when you need to query the archived data.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 added temporal tables which keep copies of order records in an archive table. You can create something similar using triggers. The only issue is that deleting/truncating the 500K table will push all 500K deleted rows to the archive table at once

Comment: As it seems right now the customer wants a backup when the database gets too large. As this might vary from few months to a few days we decide to backup the new entries each day. This would be run by a Windows Task. That I can do with my SQL knowledge but I am not sure how to do your approach destination-data and @Zohar Peled?

The customer only wants to use Express. We have recommended the other option as it would be easier for us - haha. Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Instead of creating new tables each time, just create a single archive table where you only insert the records from the main table. You should probably add a column to hold the archive date. Once the main table gets too large, copy all it's content to the archive table and truncate the main table.